# Magento widget to display in wordpress home page

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, widgets

I inserted 3 widget in CMS -> Pages. I have to do display those widgets in home page.

I used this code

```
$aCmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('main-page', 'identifier');
echo $theContent = $aCmsPage->getContent();
```

but output was like this

```
{{widget type="meigeewidgets/featuredcategory" featured_category="category/5" template="meigee/meigeewidgets/slider.phtml" products_amount="15" slider_speed="1000" slider_displayslideqty="4" slider_moveslideqty="1" slider_easing="easeInQuad" widget_id="7646"}}
```

i am new to magento. Can you please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did some digging through the CMS module in Magento and it seems that `Mage_Cms_Block_page::_toHtml` actually implements what you are looking for.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($this->getPage()->getContent());
```

Now I didn't test it but it seems that this returns the page content with the rendered widgets.