# Magento widget display wordpress home page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

i am new to magento. Can you please help me to find a solution?

Inserted 3 widget in CMS -> Pages. I have to do display those widgets in home page.

I used this code

```
$aCmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('main-page', 'identifier');
echo $theContent = $aCmsPage->getContent();
```

but output was like this

```
{{widget type="meigeewidgets/featuredcategory" featured_category="category/5" template="meigee/meigeewidgets/slider.phtml" products_amount="15" slider_speed="1000" slider_displayslideqty="4" slider_moveslideqty="1" slider_easing="easeInQuad" widget_id="7646"}}
```

I have tried this code:
echo Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($theContent);

if i add menus in magento, it will display in wp

iam not getting answer still now pls anyone can help me

Comment: Wasnt this exact same question asked 14 hours ago? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9117/magento-widget-to-display-in-wordpress-home-page

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting the raw content of the CMS page. You have to process all short-codes.

Try to:

```
echo Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($theContent);
```

Comment: no result it remains blank

Comment: the code is not working it shows blank

Comment: magento caches are flushed? anything in the logs?

Comment: yes, there are files in log and report folder